# Choose the good encoding XML-XSL to handle accentued character in my context

Tags: xml, xslt, encoding

I have a XML document which is open with IE9 by the use of XSL. The XSL file manages displaying. This document opens fine. My XML document contains some accented characters which are sometimes interpreted as HTML Link element through XSL. Yet, Those links written with accents do not work (display error page from IE browser) while others with no accents works fine. I have changed many times encoding to take account accentued character  but no change.

XML contains accented characters like

```
É,é,È,Ê,ê....
```

Please look at top headers of XML and XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="ISO-8859-1" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match = "/">
<html>
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
 ..............
 </head>
 ..............
</html>


 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
 <?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='style.xsl'?>
```

I also try using "UTF-16" instead of "ISO-8859-1" encoding in XML document, error persists while opening accented link.

Could you, please help me out and explain me what what I write does not work as I want to? 
Thanks

Comment: Did you also changes the encoding of the file or did you just changed the lable. By the way I would prefer UTF-8. That takes less space.

Comment: The file is edited with Notepad++ which uses UTF-16 for encoding; is that your question? About UTF-8, I don't think it will be appropriate in my case because XML uses non-supported  characters for UTF-8. ps: Indeed UTF-8 American Standard had forgotten french language.

Comment: Yeah basically I wanted to know if the real encoding in equal the encoding text in your XML attribute. I don't know any cases where UTF-8 cannot been used instead of UTF-16. I would be really happy if you could provide me an example.

Comment: Yes the real encoding is the same as the attribute of encoding in my xml file. By replacing all attribute both xml and xsl in "UTF-8" and chosing as encoding "UTF-8" from Notepad++ settings, the result is that XML does not use my XSL to display page. Just XML is visible in the browser. PS: About UTF-8, I was confusing with ascii. But using UTF-8, I don't still get satisfaction.Thanks

Comment: Tell us exactly which error the browser reports.

Comment: Just to make it clear, if the encoding declared (or inferred) matches the one used to create the XML then browsers can parse, transform and render ISO-8859-1 or UTF-8 just fine, see http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2013072101.xml for example which is an ISO-8859-1 encoded input XML file with an UTF-8 encoded stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without a reproducible example, but as a guess, maybe the problem isn't with the source XML or the XSLT file, but instead is a mismatch in the HTML that you output. IE might default to interpreting files as ISO-8859-1 or CP-1252, but XSLT defaults to outputting UTF-8 or UTF-16. If you're big on ISO-8859-1, add this to your XSLT:

```
<xsl:output encoding="ISO-8859-1"/>
```

Alternatively, let your XSLT output UTF-8, but let IE know by outputting this somewhere in the `head` element of the resultant HTML:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Comment: Taking account your idea, I have updated my topic. Please Let's go up to look at changes I have made in the XSL top header. That shows you the entire top header structure of the XSL. Yet the issue is always persisting on. Thanks

Comment: @new, can you post a URL where we can visit the problem? Do links to pages with accented characters work within normal HTML document, do they only fail in XSLT generated HTML? HTTP requires encoding non-ASCII characters, furthermore the XSLT spec http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-HTML-Output-Method suggests "The html output method should escape non-ASCII characters in URI attribute values using the method recommended in Section B.2.1 of the HTML 4.0 Recommendation.". I think MSXML does that, it encodes e.g `á` as `%C3%A1`. Depending on server configuration however I think that `%E1` is needed

Comment: I do that on my local computer now. If the issue persists on, I will try to post it on line. About your question, links to pages with accented characters work fine within normal HTML document.  However, F12 developer tools show the following in the console:

XML5001: Applying Integrated XSLT Handling. I don't know if it helps.